# How to simulate data in R, such that p-value of regressor is exactly 0.05?

Tags: r, simulation, linear-regression

I have written a small function that simulates data from a normal distribution, how it is usual in linear models. My question is how to get a model with a pvalue of sim[, 1] == 0.05. I want to show that if I add a random variable even it is normal distributed around zero with small variance N(0,0.0023) , that pvalue of sim[,1] changes. The code below shows the true model.

```
set.seed(37) # seed for reproducability
simulation <- function(b_0, b_1,n,min_x_1 ,max_x_1,sd_e){
      mat <- NA
      x_1 <- runif(n = n, min = min_x_1, max =max_x_1)
      error <- rnorm(mean = 0,sd = sd_e, n = n )
      y <-  b_0 + b_1*x_1 + error
      mat <- matrix(cbind(x_1,y), ncol  = 2)
      return(mat)
      #plot(mat[,1],mat[,2])
    }

    sim <- simulation(10,-2,10000,-10,70,0.003)
    summary(lm(sim[,2] ~ sim[,1] ))
```

Comment: "*that simulates data from a normal distribution, how it is usual in linear models*". Strictly speaking, it is the *residuals* that are normally distributed in a linear model; not necessarily the dependent or independent variables.

Comment: right. The errorterm must be normal distributed.